# Keycloak CORS issue on logout redirect

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, spring-security-oauth2

I am using Keycloak 10.0.2 to secure the spring boot REST API's and Angular 9 for front end.
The front end is served from the spring boot microservice running on http://localhost:8080.
On the keycloak side the openid-connect client web origin is configured to allow all origins.
Spring boot spring security is configured to use the Keycloak as  oauth2 client provider.

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          keycloak:
            issuer-uri: https://abc-keycloak.abccloud.com/auth/realms/abc
            scope: openid, profile        

        registration:
          keycloak:
            client-id: localhost
            client-secret: xxxxx
            redirect-uri: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}"
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: https://abc-keycloak.abccloud.com/auth/realms/abc
```

The angular front end makes a logout API call http://localhost:8080/logout
and is redirected to

```
 HTTP/1.1 302 Found  Location:
 https://abc-keycloak.abccloud.com/auth/realms/abc/protocol/openid-connect/logout?id_token_hint=xxxxxx
```

I am getting a CORS error in the Google Chrome browser

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://abc-keycloak.abccloud.com/auth/realms/abc/protocol/openid-connect/logout?id_token_hint=xxxxxx&post_logout_redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080'
> (redirected from 'http://localhost:8080/logout') from origin
> 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't be a API call (request in the backround). Whole browser should  be navigated to that app logout URL (and then to Keycloak logout URL).

Comment: The navigation to the keycloak logout url should also be done by the front end? What if the front end is 3rd party and I can't control it?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to force redirection. why is it OK on token_endpoint, but KO on end_session one ?

Comment: @Toilal it's easy, you need to delete cookies on IDP domain - terminate SSO session in the browser. Token endpoint is just API endpoint, so it doesn't need to handle any cookies.