# Cors issue when redirecting to external auth after logout in Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, azure-ad-b2c, camunda

I am implementing OIDC based authentication in a Spring Boot based Camunda application. I have been able to successfully implement user logging in but I am facing difficulty in logging the user out. I am using Azure B2C as the auth server and as far as I understand, I need to sign out both from the app and the auth server. Azure gives an endpoint to logout of the form `https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{policy}/oauth2/v2.0/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms%2F`.

Now, the configuration I use is as such

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    OidcUserService oidcUserService = new OidcUserService();

    http
        .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
        .and()
        .requestMatchers()
        .antMatchers("/camunda/**", "/api/**", "/login/**", "/oauth2/**")
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .oauth2Login()
        .loginPage("/oauth2/authorization/azure-ac")
        .userInfoEndpoint().oidcUserService(oidcUserService)
        .and()
        .and()
        .logout()
        .logoutUrl("/camunda/api/admin/auth/user/default/logout")
        .logoutSuccessUrl("https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{policy}/oauth2/v2.0/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms%2F");
}
```

Note: I replace the `{}` with my values.

This doesn't work as I get CORS issues in the browser.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{policy}/oauth2/v2.0/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms%2F' (redirected from 'https://localhost:6333/camunda/api/admin/auth/user/default/logout') 
from origin 'https://localhost:6333' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

This issue is very similar to [Keycloak CORS issue on logout redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64713413/keycloak-cors-issue-on-logout-redirect) but in my case, the front end is 3rd party and I would prefer not to modify it. Also in the accepted answer it is not clear if frontend must be the one to control the redirection.

Is there anyway to achieve this from Spring itself?

**EDIT:**

I have been researching and I have found some things that might be useful. Everytime the browser tries to redirect to the external url, it generates a pre-flight request. This request's response has the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://localhost:6333` headers but the actual request doesn't have the header. Reading some stuff online it seems like sending a pre flight request to servers that are not expecting one can throw them off. Moreover, the redirect request also contains the `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header. Is it possible that the presence of the XSRF header is confusing the browser? This the full `fetch` of the request.

```
fetch("https://tenant.b2clogin.com/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/policy/oauth2/v2.0/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms%2F", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "pragma": "no-cache",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-site": "cross-site",
    "x-xsrf-token": "THETOKENISHERE"
  },
  "referrer": "https://localhost:6333/",
  "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
  "body": null,
  "method": "GET",
  "mode": "cors",
  "credentials": "omit"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With Spring Security access to Cross-origin sites/URLs are blocked unless you configure it

Sample Example

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("https://localhost:6333"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

This is just a sample we can fine-tune list and method based on the requirement.

Comment: I don't know what I am doing wrong but adding this bean hasn't made any changes to what I am facing. I have even added the b2c endpoint in the list of allowed origins. Moreover, I don't know if my understanding is correct but isn't CORS used when a different website is trying to access my resource? In my case, I want the server to tell the browser to redirect to an external site. I am not sure if they are different cases in the first place.

Comment: Regarding your CORS query. That's a good question. I guess you need to add CORS configuration other way around. Inside your external site.

Comment: But the external site is the 3rd party Auth server. I don't have control over its origin policies. I have been reading and I will add some more information that might be relevant.

Comment: @SayakMukhopadhyay I'm facing the same problem when redirecting to a external SSO server. Did you make any progress about this issue? Regards.